# How to make camera start faster

Tags: camera, performance

Everyone knows that start Android camera sometimes is a pain, specially if you wish to take a picture of something that lasts only some seconds. What I want to know is: is there a way or an app that makes the camera start faster?

**Note** that I'm not asking about picture shot, though this is important too. I think that as soon as the camera is started, this is not a big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [InstaCamera Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longwell.instant.camera.pro) from Google Play Store. It starts very fast and has preferences to start camera and takes photo just by a single touch from home screen of your phone:

> InstaCamera is the quickest way to take a photo with your phone.
>
> There's no long process: just press the widget and it takes a photo, then closes just as quickly.

The [paid PRO version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longwell.instant.camera.pro) is supposed to be faster than the [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=longwell.instant.camera).

Comment: Can't find this exact app, can you provide the link so I can be sure which app you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If any app takes significant time to open, it means that app is heavy on resources and/or there's high load on system. Before bringing any app in memory, Android first makes room for it in memory (technically, it happens based on [minfree](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.prftungd/doc/prftungd/values_minfree_maxfree_param.htm) value even if there's room for that app).

So, to solve the issue, do these things:

- Reduce load from system. Less running apps in memory means less probability of minfree based ju-ju.
- Use a lightweight camera app. Lightweight apps are loaded in memory faster and again there's less probability of minfree based ju-ju.
  There are many lightweight camera apps in Play Store. Just, search "Fast Camera".

Answer (score 2):

I have done a serious research on this topic and i found that **all device has an opening lag** and it is independent of your camera applications i.e, it is hardware dependent. It(the lag) will be keep varying depending on the memory and processor state. Some smartphones are successful in covering it with their high end hardware resources.

**Consider a scenario** : if we have a bundle of apps opened in memory and you opened camera with any of your camera application then you feel lagging more than before. Now you can understand easily that this lagging time is a varying factor.

i have even created an application for this called "camera opening lag checker" it calculates your camera lag time and allows you to compare it with  world's top devices real time.

Meizu PRO 5's camera opened in .17ms where Samsung s6,s7 are also performing great with .25ms, .26 respectively

Thank You

Comment: Jayakrishnan, do you still have that camera opening lag checker app that you could share? Perhaps a GitHub link?

Comment: @Scampbell now the app is not available in Google Play Store.